# how to set custom permalink in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to change the permalinks of WordPress website. Because I want to create multi country website without creating sub-domains. For now I am having link like :

```
https://example.com/
https://example.com/categroy/post-link
```

But I want to do like:

```
https://example.com/country-code/
https://example.com/country-code/category/post-link
```

I've tried many google searches but no one have the solutions. Please let me know if this is possible. Small help can make this work.

Regards

Comment: Do you want `https://example.com/country-code1/category/post-link` and `https://example.com/country-code2/category/post-link` to serve the same WordPress post? Or two different posts entirely?

Comment: same as wordpress post